# Can I use Bean class variable to <f:validateRegex pattern"#{bean.beanVariable}">

Tags: jsf

I am working with settings part in my project. I want to get the form attributes from the DB like maxlength, minlength, pattern etc.
    I want to use my bean class variable as a pattern String. Is that Possible? minlength, maxlength attributes works fine using bean class variable, but validateRegex is not working

Bean code

```
    @Service
    class CategoryBean {
        String categoryNamePattern;
        String showForm(){
            categoryNamePattern = "([a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]*)";
            return "myform.xhtml";
        }
    }
```

myform.xhtml With bean class variable for regex pattern

```
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory.name}">
        <f:validateRegex for="name" pattern="#{categeoryBean.categoryNamePattern}"/>
    </p:inputText>
```

myform.xhtml This Works fine with pattern defined inside

```
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory.name}">
        <f:validateRegex for="name" pattern="([a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]*)"/>
    </p:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay..
My form is not validating the regex when i give it to the bean variable.. It accept nothing..

Comment: I understood, Then I have to include Omnifaces validator tag right?   which package I have to mention in validatorId

Comment: Actually I am not having any iterating components. just a single.  I had done everytjing in Primeface does I need to move to Omniface to do this one feature alone

Comment: Sorry @BalusC, Please see the edited question..

Comment: refer the question @BalusC

Comment: @BalusC thanks for your time. I got an alternate solution.

Comment: Refer the MVCE recommendations http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info You can't get proper answers otherwise.

Comment: I am new here that's the problem I will be updated questions with clear explanation here after. thanks for your guidance @BalusC

Comment: Your actual problem appears to be that in your object, you have named the property `catNamePattern`, but in your form you have referred to it as `categoryNamePattern`.  You need to use the same name in both places, otherwise, how is the program to know what you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I did with validator tag. wrote a new validator method
    This works fine.

```
          @Service
        class CategoryBean {
            String catNamePattern;
            String showForm(){
                categoryNamePattern = "([a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z ]*)";
                return "myform.xhtml";
            }

     public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if (catNamePattern != null) {
                RegexValidator regexValidator = new RegexValidator();
                regexValidator.setPattern(categoryNamePattern);
                regexValidator.validate(context, component, value);
            }
        }
    }

 <p:inputText id="name" value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory.name}">
        <f:validateRegex for="name" pattern="#{categeoryBean.categoryNamePattern}" validator="#{categoryBean.validate}" />
    </p:inputText>
```